# PHPExcel: auto wrap long text (without spaces) in PDF

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

How can I auto wrap long word (without spaces) while creating PDF?

Example word = `Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooo` .

I tried this

```
// This is for each column    
$this->sheet->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setWidth(10);

// This is for full data cells ranges.
$this->sheet->getStyle($fullRange)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

and it works fine for Excel output but not for PDF output.

Comment: You can't wrap text without spaces or line breaks.... how would you expect MS Excel to do it?

Comment: @MarkBaker: It works for Excel output. issue is with PDF. Just modified question.